# Charset in HTML from (at-sign) despite of utf-8 header and accept-charset

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

Using e-mail for login, I figured out that there are (probably) problems with the charset of the HTML-form...

At the very top of the document I use php for:

`header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

In the head-section I also have:

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

and even in the form itself:

`<form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>`

However, when serializing the form the e-mail address is being return as follows:

`email=my%40email.com`

Does anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CoursesWeb is right with this. Use `urldecode($_POST['email']);` and it will automatically decode the string with all `%##` in it.

From php.net:

> string urldecode ( string $str ) Decodes any %## encoding in the given
>   string. Plus symbols ('+') are decoded to a space character.

(php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is from some code in the PHP script that filters theform data.